# latexmk -pvc doesn't recompile if included files change

Tags: xetex, latexmk

My current project layout looks like this:

`Mainfile.tex` with `\begin{document}` including

- preamble (`\documentclass`, packages, newcommands, etc) and
- chapters, split into separate subfiles.

I'm using the following `.latexmkrc` to compile with `latexmk -pvc -pdf Mainfile.tex`:

```perl
$pdflatex = "xelatex -src-specials -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
$pdf_previewer = "evince %O %S";
$pdf_update_method = 0;
$sleep_time = 1;

push @cus_dep_list, "nlo nls 0 nlo2nls";
sub nlo2nls {
    system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
```

The document compiles perfectly without errors, but `latexmk` never recompiles it no matter whether I change the main file or one of the included subfiles.

Any ideas?

Edit: John Collins' right. Not using "start" was the culprit here.

Comment: The line setting the pdf_previewer needs to be $pdf_previewer = "start evince %O %S"; with 'start' in front of 'evince'.  Otherwise latexmk starts evince and waits for it to terminate.

Comment: @JohnCollins your comment should have been an answer. ;) Scratched my head over this for a few hours.

Comment: @Alex: The current form of your question is confusing, as the edited script doesn't produce (anymore) the behaviour you describe. I suggest to undo the last edit and either to either wait for John Collins to write an answer or to write a separate (self-)answer.

Comment: @lockstep Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: @JohnCollins Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line that sets `$pdf_previewer` needs to be

```
$pdf_previewer = "start evince %O %S";
```

with 'start' in front of 'evince'.  Otherwise, when `latexmk` runs `evince`, it waits for `evince` to terminate, instead of running `evince` detached

(I probably ought to change `latexmk`'s behavior so that it does the detaching of a previewer automatically when it's in continuous preview mode.)